# redirect to route result resource not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i have an action filter which implements a basic check to see if the user is authenticated.

if the user is not authenticated i've implemented this:

> ```
>         var routeValue = new RouteValueDictionary
>                              {                                     
>                                  {"Controller", "Permission"},
>                                  {"Action", "NoAccess"}
>                              };
>
>         filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValue);
>
>         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
> ```

ok this works and points the user to:

http://localhost:/Permission/NoAccess

but the problem starts to happen when i reload my project and the user is then redirected to:

http://localhost:/Views/Permission/NoAccess.aspx

and i get the error: The resource cannot be found.

slightly confused why it works once then breaks again after a reload? any suggestions?maybe i should be redirecting using another method?

using IIS express, visual studio 2010, MVC2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an unfortunate feature of Visual Studio...

If you have the view NoAccess.aspx open in Visual Studio and then press F5, Visual Studio opens the Internet Explorer with the URL `http:/localhost:11111/Views/Permission/NoAccess.aspx`. This URL might work for a classic ASP.NET application, but it doesn't for ASP.NET MVC applications. And it's basically a bug in Visual Studio and certainly not in your application.

If you open a .cs file and then press F5, Visual Studio will start Internet Explorer with the URL `http:/localhost:11111/`.

I'm not sure this applies to your problem because I don't know what you mean by *reload your project*. But it might be what your seeing.

Comment: yeah i assume its an VS bug.. because i can restart the app ..and its hit or miss if it works or not.  i'll leave this question open for a llittle while longer and if no other feedback i'll give you the points for the answer.  thanks mate